# colorbox plugin not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

I am new to Drupal but I have not had any issues so far since I strictly followed all the documentation.

But this one issue, I just cant resolve it.

I installed the Colorbox module.

I followed all the documentation; enabled the settings, added `colorbox-load` inside the link class but its just not working!

Please advise me on this issue, I didnt know anywhere else to ask...

test link; [click here](http://kampuster.com/beta2/node/2)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're trying to load in the colorbox. For images, you simply add the "colorbox" class to your image link. For example:

a class="colorbox" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.png" rel="1" title="This is my image."

If you're trying to use colorbox-load (to open a page or form in a colorbox) you have to be sure to check the "Enable colorbox load" box on your colorbox config page (admin/config/media/colorbox on D7) and format the link as follows:

a class="colorbox-load" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.png" rel="1" "

Also be sure you download the colorbox library and add it to your sites/all/libraries folder if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the display formatter of a field type Image. Also the [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1971564) says to add the class "**colorbox**" in the links!

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).